# How to execute multiple queries as a batch

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, entitymanager

I have to execute multiple queries as a batch update

I have below code

```
        List<BigInteger> queryObj= new ArrayList<BigInteger>();
        queryObj.add(new BigInteger("92408"));
        queryObj.add(new BigInteger("92409"));
        queryObj.add(new BigInteger("92410"));
        queryObj.add(new BigInteger("92411"));
        for(BigInteger id : queryObj){
        Query q = entityManager.createQuery("update LineItemMeta set name = :name where 
                  lineItemMetaId = :lineItemMetaId");
              q.setParameter("name","abcd");
              q.setParameter("lineItemMetaId", id);
        }
        entityManager.persist(listOfQuery);
```

This **entityManager.persist** doesn't work.

Please suggest any alternate way using **spring data jpa**

Comment: Please read https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/